# VS for Mac - Am I working on code covered by unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

On regular VS, using a enterprise licence, there's a little annotation above the method declaration which says something like "passing 12/15".

Is there a way to discover if I'm altering a code that is being covered by unit tests on VS for Mac?

Comment: That code coverage tool has been logged as a "suggestion" since late 2018...that and there is no code lens to help some of the navigation insights. Someday I will be able to retire my windows image for dev but not yet.